# Paste option is disable in the vmware

Tags: windows-7

I am not able to paste the files which i have copied from local machine to VMware machine.Please any one can help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Drag and drop works on VMware . Just drag the file you want to VMware and drop it there.

And here is eHow article. [How to Drag-and-Drop in VMware](http://www.ehow.com/how_7192031_drag_and_drop-vmware.html).